# How can I access to component state content?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the React Slick library to create carousel components. In the constructor I define the following state:

```js
class ArticlesContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lists: [],
      settings: {
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        arrows: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

And after an event I call this.setState like this:

```jsx
this.setState(prevState => ({
  lists: response.data,
  settings: {
    ...prevState.settings,
    customPaging: function(i) {
      console.log(this.state.lists);

      return <a>{i}</a>;
    },
  },
}));
```

The problem is that when I call `console.log(this.state.lists)`, it says that it's undefined. How can I access the lists property of my component, from `customPaging`?

Comment: Before setting you new state, did you check what `response.data` looks like?

Comment: Yes, it's working as intended. But now that you mention it, I could use that for `customPaging`. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Consider revising the `customPaging` callback to an arrow function, rather than a "regular function":

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  lists: response.data,
  settings: {
    ...prevState.settings,
    customPaging: (i) => {

      // "this" will now correspond to the component instance
      // meaning that this.state will be the current state of
      // your outer ArticlesContainer component
      console.log(this.state.lists);

      return <a>{i}</a>;
    },
  },
}));
```

This will cause the context of the `customPaging` callback to be that of your component, allowing you to access the `state.lists` array of your `<ArticlesContainer />` component instance.